# How to resolve 'Process unexpectedly closed with status 11' for Selenium in IPython?

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, ipython, geckodriver

I run the following code in `IPython` (from official Python extension VSCode):

```
# %%
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path='.driver/geckodriver')
```

It gives me the following errors:

- For GeckoDriver 0.28.0

```
WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 11
```

- For GeckkoDriver 0.27.0:

```
WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

My setup:

```
Firefox: 82.0
GeckoDriver: 0.28.0
Selenium: 3.141.0
IPython: 7.19.0
Ubuntu: 20.10
Python3 venv
```

**Note:** This script works in terminal but not `IPython`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with Firefox driver and I change it to Chrome driver it works well now

```
# install chromium, its driver, and selenium
!apt update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!pip install selenium

# set options to be headless, ..
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# open it, go to a website, and get results
wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wd.get("https://www.website.com")

print(wd.page_source)  # results
```

Comment: Yes, this works indeed. The problem seems to be with geckodriver (0.28) and the latest firefox (82.0)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I installed the same configuration as yours on my computer. When I run the code in the `.py` file and `.ipynb` file in VSCode, the result can be displayed:

[image]

[image]

It is recommended that you check the following aspects:

1. Make sure that the kernel "`ipykernel`" required by Jupyter has been installed in your currently selected VSCode environment.
2. Please check the execution path of "`geckodriver`" in the code.
3. Please try to reload VSCode or restart VSCode or even your computer if conditions permit.

Comment: Thanks @jill-cheng for your answer, I tried everything you suggested but nothing works. I suspect the it is bug from latest geckodriver release.

Comment: @huy_trvan -I noticed that you also have a description [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8851), so I post this link here so people can get more information about it.